# Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} [0,1-1/n] \subset [0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} [0,1-1/n] \subset [0,1)$. Let $ a \in \bigcup_{n\geq 1} [0,1-1/n]$ then there exists a $N\geq 1$ s.t. $ 0 \leq a \leq 1 - 1/N$ since $1-1/N < 1$ then $a \in [0,1)$ is this correct or am I missing something

Comment: That's fine. ${}{}$

Comment: It's actually equal.