# Infinite union clarification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am 99% sure but still I want some clarification. Is it true that:
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}[0,\frac{n-1}{n})=[0,1]$$

Comment: No.$~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: Related posts: [Show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} [0,1-1/n] \subset [0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1613917), [Represent the interval [0,1) by union](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983617), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is false; it's actually $[0,1)$, with an open endpoint at $1$. This is because $1$ is not in any set $[0, \frac{n-1}{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

No -

Notice for any $n$ you want, $1 \not \in [0,1 - 1/n)$. Then $1$ is not in the union either.

Indeed, $\bigcup_n [0, 1 - 1/n) = [0,1)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, thats what I thought